# Is connecting to a proxy server with HTTP for a HTTPS Request secure?

Tags: http, https, proxy, http-proxy, proxy-server

I have a use case where I would like to connect to a proxy server with `HTTP`, but the underlying request is actually a `GET` with `HTTPS`. I have been reading [When should one use CONNECT and GET HTTP methods at HTTP Proxy Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697943/when-should-one-use-connect-and-get-http-methods-at-http-proxy-server/40329026#40329026), but I think i need some clarification. Since the underlying request is `HTTPS` does this mean when I "connect" to my proxy server it will automatically open a `CONNECT` and just pass through my `HTTPS` request? My main concern is if I use `HTTP` to connect to my proxy server, then the underlying `HTTPS` request is somehow exposed until it hits the proxy server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, whatever your browser says inside a https session is encrypted before, during, and after it passes through a proxy. No, it is not exposed to a proxy. For a proxy, the HTTP `CONNECT` means just "copy raw bytes around without any interpretation". The proxy does see in plain text the part of url that is in caps here:  **HTTPS`://`EXAMPLE.COM:9443**/secret/place. It doesn't see the rest of url or anything else; doesn't see headers or data. (If a proxy is really intrusive and decrypts and re-encrypts your session it is visible via a certificate. Your browser would need to be compromised to trust a man-in-the-middle certificate. Uncompromised browser quite visibly warns you.)

Practically, using http only between a browser and a proxy is presently the most popular way of proxying.